# Handling Security in Asp.net MVC pages with ActionFilters and sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an requirement to show an alert when user's session has expired and redirect to login page.
Actually I have created an Action filter which is applied on a controller and it checks 
if session is expired , if es it redirects to login page otherwise it lets the action complete 
successfully.

It is working fine but my problem arises when I make ajax request.
For an instance I have ajax.beginform in my view and I have done saving code on that acion
method. Now, suppose user has submitted the form when session has expired,
before the saving method runs, my actionFilter called up because I have set it at the 
controller, So, from there it says, redirect to login page.
But I am returning Json from controller and it do not redirects.

How  should I implement the things?

My code is::::::::::::

For every controller, my Action Filter is defined in same way, I am just going to define only for one controller So, suppose below is my controller.

```
[CheckSessions]
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
             public ActionResult Add(Model model)
        {
                 Insert code and returns 
                return Json(new { Msg = Message});
         }
    }

Action Filter is here
   public class CheckSessions: ActionFilterAttribute
    { 
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginSession"] == null && HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginSession"] == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/LoginController/Login");
            }
}
}


In View Page:::
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "MyController ", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "MessageConfirmation" }))
            {
   Content goes here
}

<script>
Getting Response

    function MessageConfirmation(Json) {
        alert(Json.StatusCode);
if(Json.StatusCode==404)
{
 redirect to login
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not perform the `Response.Redirect` for the Ajax request.

Instead redirect you send the response text/code that says the session expires, and redirect using `window.location.href`

```
 public class CheckSessions: ActionFilterAttribute
 { 
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
      if (HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginSession"] == null && 
       HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginSession"] == null)
      {
           if(HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
             HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode="401"; //Session Expired
            }
           else
            {
             HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
            }

       }
    }
  }
```

In Javascript/jQuery check status code ==="401"

**OPTION 1:**

new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "MessageConfirmation(data, status, xhr)" }

function MessageConfirmation(data, status, xhr)
{

```
 //check the status code from xhr
 window.location.href="/Account/Login";
```

}

**Option 2:** do it globally

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    401: function(xhr) {
      window.location.href="/Account/Login";
    }
  }
```

});

Comment: but how will I send the status, by json? Please give your suggestion.

Comment: @Sweetie, just set the `HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType ="application/json"` if it is a JSON request

Comment: @Sweetie, it is not required to set the content type, since you are dealing with request status, which will be available for all jQuery ajax requests, including GET,POST, JSONP, etc

Comment: Suppose by this line I have set status Code  ..... HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode="401"; 
Now How will I check in Java script as I am getting response  in succes method of Ajax,Begin form

Comment: Just go with status code and check the response code what the ajax call returns. if you use jquery

Comment: I have updated my question . Can you please check the view section if I am getting the response in right way?